# c fill a two-dimensional array using a helper function

Tags: c

I keep getting a segmentation fault:

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 50

void fill_matrix(char *pointer[], char c) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {

      // tried many syntaxes

      // *(*(pointer + i) + j) = c;
      // *(pointer + i)[j] = c;
      // pointer[i][j] = c;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
  fill_matrix(&matrix, ' ');
}
```

How are 2D arrays supposed to be accessed by helper methods? Pointers are confusing me!

Comment: In your case, you can replace the fill_matrix call to : `memset(matrix, ' ', sizeof(matrix))`

Comment: @benjarobin not gonna get too fancy to start off :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void fill_matrix(char pointer[][MATRIX_SIZE], char c) {
```

will work, but if you want a pointer style:

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 50

void fill_matrix(char (*pointer)[MATRIX_SIZE], char c) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {
      pointer[i][j]= c;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
  fill_matrix(matrix, ' ');
}
```

Note that there is no need to use `&` to pass the array

Also note that in this case you don't need a helper function,

```
memset(matrix, ' ', sizeof matrix);
```

will do the work

Answer (score 2):

Just declare your function as:

```
void fill_matrix(char matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE], char c);
```

and then call it like this

```
fill_matrix(matrix, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing to the function a different object than the one you've declared. What you've declared is a *two-dimensional array*. What the function expects, is an *array of pointers to one-dimensional arrays*. You can't cast one into another seamlessly. To fix you should either make `fill_matrix()` take a 2-dim array (with all C-specific idiosyncrasy) or allocate your `matrix` as an array of pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your function should use an array of the same type you are defining in `main`:

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 50

void fill_matrix(char pointer[][MATRIX_SIZE], char c) {
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++) {

      pointer[i][j] = c;
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char matrix[MATRIX_SIZE][MATRIX_SIZE];
  fill_matrix(matrix, ' ');
}
```

Comment: You should specify the second element in the matrix when you are declaring the definition of the function, not the first. This code does not compile.